# Why is Stream.BeginRead() synchronous?

Tags: c#

The Stream.BeginRead() takes a callback function as one of the parameters. That callback function should be called asynchronously, but .net fakes that by calling callback function from the BeginRead() directly. Why is that happening? It seems like there is no difference between Read() and BeginRead().
Please see the stack view below:

[image: stack view]

Comment: Assuming there is data available immediately, why *wouldn't* you want it to call you back synchronously?

Comment: fwiw, the documentatation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread(v=vs.110).aspx) calls out this behavior on the base `Stream.BeginRead()` implementation.

Comment: IIRC the default Stream implementation passes all asynchronous calls onto the synchronous methods. It's down to the implementer of the subclass to provide asynchronous method implementations. They're not conjured up by default. It's possible that the Stream implementation you are using has no implementation for the APM methods. The Task based methods use the APM methods by default.

Comment: @spender your comment seems to be the answer:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the documentation for `Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates:

> **The default implementation of BeginRead on a stream calls the Read method synchronously**, which means that Read might block on some streams. However, instances of classes such as FileStream and NetworkStream fully support asynchronous operations if the instances have been opened asynchronously. Therefore, calls to BeginRead will not block on those streams. **You can override BeginRead (by using async delegates, for example) to provide asynchronous behavior**.

In other words, it is up to each `Stream` sub-class to provide true asynchronous behavior.

Now, in the case of the `ConnectStream` you see in your stack trace, that's another .NET class (internal, undocumented) and it actually *does* provide an asynchronous implementation of `BeginRead()`. This can be seen in [the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_ConnectStream.cs,64625af05da37576). But, there's another important rule for asynchronous operations generally: **asynchronous operations following [the APM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) may in fact complete synchronously**. There's even [a property on IAsyncResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously(v=vs.110).aspx) to indicate this occurrence.

This in fact turns out to be the case for many asynchronous APIs. For example, when using `await`, it is possible that the method will *not* return at the `await` expression, but instead will retrieve the completion result immediately and just keep on executing in the current thread. This happens not only when the awaitable is just a synchronous operation dressed up in an asynchronous wrapper, but also when what would normally be an asynchronous operation can in fact be completed synchronously.

I'm sure that if you were to check the `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` property in your callback, you would find it was set to `true`, as it's supposed to be when the API completes an asynchronous operation synchronously. That property exists primarily for this very scenario, in case your own code needs to distinguish between operations that complete asynchronously and those that complete synchronously (in general, it shouldn't, but we all know code isn't always as it should be, and even sometimes can't be :) ).

Comment: The following part is simply wrong: instances of classes such as FileStream and NetworkStream fully support asynchronous operations if the instances have been opened asynchronously. I know the documentation says so, but it is NOT true. I guess it is just one the many .net craps.

Comment: @moose: cite, please. Because there's plenty of examples of asynchronous code using asynchronous operations for both classes. `FileStream` requires the use of `FileOptions.Asynchronous`, of course. There, if you fail to initialize the object correctly, you won't get the behavior you want. But `NetworkStream.BeginRead()` _always_ goes straight to `Socket.BeginReceive()`, which itself is definitely asynchronous.

Comment: I don't know what to say, but I see the stack with my own eyes. What it shows is synchronous. Based on what the documentation says, I would say that you can use BeginRead() and some internal logic will decide if it is going to be async or sync. Not useful at all (to me).

Comment: @moose: the stack trace you included in your post involves neither `FileStream` nor `NetworkStream`. Also, as I've already explained in the answer above, even a `Stream` that supports asynchronous operation _can_ and _will_ complete _some_ operations synchronously, i.e. when it is more efficient to do so. Why _wouldn't_ you want an operation to complete synchronously when possible?

Comment: I can create a new question, but I'll try here first. What type of stream will `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseStream()` return? `FileStream`, `NetworkStream`, or something else? I seriously doubt it will be a `FileStream`, but again... I would not be surprised.

Comment: @moose: as can easily be seen [in the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebResponse.cs,afb69c196ac0f9c0), `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()` returns an instance of the internal class `ConnectStream`, or in some cases an instance of `WebSocketConnectionStream` (also an internal class).

Comment: thanks. I upvoted your answer as a way of thanking you for your time and effort. Now I will run back to the environment that I understand much better (C++).